# Is it viable to test wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, system.io.file

I have class and interface like this:

```cs
public interface IFileIOWrapper
{
    bool Exists(string path);
    string ReadAllText(string path);
    void WriteAllText(string path, string text);
    long FileSize(string path);
}

public class FileIOWrapper : IFileIOWrapper
{
    public bool Exists(string path)
    {
        return File.Exists(path);
    }

    public string ReadAllText(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(path);
    }

    public void WriteAllText(string path, string text)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, text);
    }

    public long FileSize(string path)
    {
        return new FileInfo(path).Length;
    }
}
```

I tested only `IFileIOWrapper` to make sure that it's gets and return appropiate types.

```cs
public class FileIOWrapper_Tests
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("CI")]
    public void FileIOWrapper_ReadAllText()
    {
        var fileIOWrapper = new Mock<IFileIOWrapper>();
        var exampleText = "mellon";
        fileIOWrapper.Setup(x => x.ReadAllText(It.Is<string>(y => y == exampleText))).Returns(exampleText);

        var result = fileIOWrapper.Object.ReadAllText(exampleText);

        Assert.AreEqual(exampleText, result);
    }
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("CI")]
    public void FileIOWrapper_WriteAllText()
    {
        var fileIOWrapper = new Mock<IFileIOWrapper>();
        var dir = @"C:\mellon";
        var exampleText = "mellon";
        fileIOWrapper.Setup(x => x.WriteAllText(It.Is<string>(y => y == dir), It.Is<string>(y => y == exampleText)));

        fileIOWrapper.Object.WriteAllText(dir, exampleText);

        fileIOWrapper.Verify(x => x.WriteAllText(It.Is<string>(y => y == dir), It.Is<string>(y => y == exampleText)));
    }
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("CI")]
    public void FileIOWrapper_Exists()
    {
        var fileIOWrapper = new Mock<IFileIOWrapper>();
        var dir = @"C:\mellon";
        fileIOWrapper.Setup(x => x.Exists(It.Is<string>(y => y == dir))).Returns(true);

        var response = fileIOWrapper.Object.Exists(dir);

        Assert.IsTrue(response);
    }
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("CI")]
    public void FileIOWrapper_FileSize()
    {
        var fileIOWrapper = new Mock<IFileIOWrapper>();
        var dir = @"C:\mellon";
        var fileSizeInBytes = 3018;
        fileIOWrapper.Setup(x => x.FileSize(It.Is<string>(y => y == dir))).Returns(fileSizeInBytes);

        var result = fileIOWrapper.Object.FileSize(dir);

        Assert.AreEqual(fileSizeInBytes, result);
    }
}
```

I have all the validation of paths etc. in others class which depend on this class so there is no need for validation here.
My question is should I still test `FileIOWrapper` when it only covers pure static .NET classes and methods? If so how should I do it because almost every article that I've read stops at making a wrapper testing an abstraction and nothing more.

Comment: What prompted you to write this `FileIOWrapper` in the first place? What value is it adding to your project that you can't get from the existing `FileInfo` class?

Comment: You don't need to test the interface because it does not have any method implemented. You can write tests for `FileIOWrapper` but they are not guaranteed to be passed in all environments as they are dependent on the file system and does not have any logic.

Comment: "I tested only IFileIOWrapper to make sure that it's gets and return appropiate types." Those tests really aren't testing anything in the normal sense of the word. Interfaces generally don't have tests: implementations do.

Comment: @Dai: Presumably testability for the code that *uses* `IFileIOWrapper`. Effectively abstracting away the file system allows tests to be written *as if* files were present, without them *actually* being present.

Comment: @JonSkeet so making sure via tests that for example method returns string is not a good approach? Because for me if I would like to change smth in the method in the future and then the test fail it will definetly make me think twice cuz someone intended to make it work this way to keep right flow in the rest of aplication.

Comment: @Chetan so the class is untestable in your opinion or it's testable but needs to be rewritten certain way?

Comment: You shouldn't test to make sure that your method returns a string. The interface says it does, and if you change it the compiler will tell you so. You need to delete those "tests". They don't exercise one bit of code in your application, which tests are meant to do.